# Выстроить элементы bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В общем дело вот в чем. Есть такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу костылями сделать, но не хочется(
Подскажите, есть ли элегантный способ. Код:

```css
.circles__item {
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #5f5f5f;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 43px;
}

.circles__item p {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #5f5f5f;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="circles d-flex">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="circles__item">
            1
            <p>Simple</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="circles__item">
            2
            <p>Transparent</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="circles__item">
            3
            <p>Collaborative</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а вы не подключили bootstrap 4 .

Comment: Это лишь кусок кода) Там все подключено)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускать в полно экранном режиме.
Обернул цифры в тег.

```css
.circles__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.circles__item span {
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #5f5f5f;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 43px;
  display: block;
}

.circles__item p {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="circles__item">
          <span>1</span>
          <p>Simple</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="circles__item">
          <span>2</span>
          <p>Transparent</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="circles__item">
          <span>3</span>
          <p>Collaborative</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Примерно раньше так и пробовал. Теперь понял, что упустил. Спасибо.